# nullpointerexception in wyswig xml layout in eclipse for android and visual-artifacts

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, tabwidget, visual-artifacts

I'm currently developing an application for Android which needs to use a custom made Tabs. I have encountered two problems:

I will start from my first problem:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.TabWidget.initTabWidget(TabWidget.java:115)
at android.widget.TabWidget.<init>(TabWidget.java:86)
at android.widget.TabWidget.<init>(TabWidget.java:69)
...
```

I'm getting this exception when i want to switch from a text mode to wyswig mode in Eclipse.
This is the actual xml code that gives me that error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

       <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dip"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:padding="20dip"
           android:background="#fff" />

       <RadioGroup android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:checkedButton="@+id/first"
           android:id="@+id/states">
           <RadioButton android:id="@+id/first"
               android:background="#FF00FF"
               android:width="80dip"
               android:height="70dip" />
           <RadioButton android:id="@+id/second"
               android:background="#FFFFFF"
               android:width="80dip"
               android:height="70dip" />
           <RadioButton android:id="@+id/third"
               android:background="#00FFFF"
               android:width="80dip"
               android:height="70dip" />
           <RadioButton android:id="@+id/fourth"
               android:background="#0000FF"
               android:width="80dip"
               android:height="70dip" />
       </RadioGroup>

      <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="0"
          android:visibility="gone" />  
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Now the second problem is an Graphic-Artifact:
[image: http://img529.imageshack.us/img529/8216/99725485.png]

How can i resolve my problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix what i though was a visual-artifact:

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:background="#FFFFFF" />
```

also it seems that whenever i use TabHost and TabWidget in my projects i'm getting that exception, also i have checked it on android tutorials: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html
and yes i have got it too

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty obvious what is wrong and also the message in Eclipse tells you quite exactly what the mistake is. Your `FrameLayout` has no content.

What are you trying to achieve with that `FrameLayout`?

**UPDATE:** Just realized what you were trying to do. Try this layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="20dip"
            android:background="#fff">
            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:checkedButton="@+id/first"
                android:id="@+id/states">
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@id/first"
                    android:background="#FF00FF"
                    android:width="80dip"
                    android:height="70dip"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/second"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:width="80dip"
                    android:height="70dip"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/third"
                    android:background="#00FFFF"
                    android:width="80dip"
                    android:height="70dip"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/fourth"
                    android:background="#0000FF"
                    android:width="80dip"
                    android:height="70dip"/>
            </RadioGroup>
        </FrameLayout>
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

I've also corrected another mistake for you. Actually not necessarily a mistake but still. In the `RadioGroup` you are assigning the first `RadioButton` the ID `first` with `android:checkedButton="@+id/first"` when you're referencing it. When you actually get to the `RadioButton` your ID definition should not contain a `+` anymore. Check out the layout.